# Weirdness using jquery's .html() function to set <a></a> with a special character &#10003; (checkmark)

Tags: jquery, webkit

I'm trying to have the following  tag toggle between a "-" and the checkmark character (&#10003)

```
<a id='p_4' class='fancy_button orange bls_button' href='#'>-</a>
```

And here's the jquery code:

```
        if (button.text() == '-') {
            button.html('&#10003'); }
```

This works in FF3.6 and IE8, but not in WebKit (Chrome or iPhone safari).

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or does webkit just not like .html("&#10003")

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: If VoteyDisciple's answer was (as it seems) the correct one, please click the hollow checkmark just to the left of the beginning of the answer (under the up and down arrows). Doing so says that that answer correctly answered your question, which is important for a Q&A site like SO.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget the trailing semicolon:

```
button.html('&#10003;');
```

Comment: +1 for beating me by 7 seconds (and the exact same answer); wonder if it's really the problem

Comment: Wow... can't believe I missed that. I've been banging my head against the wall wondering what was wrong.

Thank you soo soo much!

Comment: And yes, that was the problem. Apparently FF is forgiving enough to display the character without the semicolon, but Chrome, not so much.